# Passing types of props to reusable component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, types, react-props

How can I *take advantage* of the type of source (fullName) declared in the parent component where the prop is declared inside the child component?

e.g.

```
type fullNameProps = {
   name: string;
   last: string;
}

const App = () => {
   const fullName: fullNameProps = {
     name: "John",
     last: "Doe",
   } 

   return <ChildComponent source={fullName} />

};
```

How can I use the type of **source** in the ChildComponent declared in App Component? The **source** object could vary since ChildComponent is a reusable component. Is there a way I can use Generics for that?

```
const ChildComponent = ({ source }: { source ??? }) => {};
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using `source: node`? Node would be the propType.
Or Better yet you could account for multiple types as follows:

```
  optionalUnion: PropTypes.oneOfType([
    PropTypes.string,
    PropTypes.number,
    PropTypes.instanceOf(Message)
  ]),
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @bnjmn.myers My example is much simpler than the real case. I'm trying to find a solution with Typescript Generics. I believe it must have a way around for that, but I can't quite figure it out.

Comment: Did you give the PropTypes.node a shot?

Comment: Additionally, I just found this... PropTypes.any

Comment: Using PropTypes.any is equivalent to signing my typescript type to any.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe first we'll have to convert the ChildComponent to a *generic* component. It would look something like this:

```js
interface ChildComponentProps<T = unknown> {
    source: T
}

function ChildComponent<T extends any>(props: ChildComponentProps<T>) {
    return (
    <div>...</div>
    )
}
```

Now, we use this component by providing the type for its source. Something like this:

```js
interface AppProps {
// your app's props
}

type FullNameProps = {
    name: string;
    last: string;
}

const App: React.FC<AppProps> = (props) => {
    const fullName: FullNameProps = {
        name: "John",
        last: "Doe",
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <ChildComponent<FullNameProps>
                source={fullName}
            />
        </div>
    )
}
```

This should do the work. Also, providing a render method to your child component to render the value passed in the source is recommended.

**The whole example with render function included**:

```js
interface AppProps {
// your app's props
}

type FullNameProps = {
    name: string;
    last: string;
}

const App: React.FC<AppProps> = (props) => {

    const fullName: FullNameProps = {
        name: "John",
        last: "Doe",
    }

    const renderItem = (item: FullNameProps) => {
        return (
            <h1>
                {item.name} {item.last}
            </h1>
        )
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <ChildComponent<FullNameProps>
                source={fullName}
                renderItem={renderItem}
            />
        </div>
    )
}


interface ChildComponentProps<T = unknown> {
    source: T
    renderItem: (item: T) => JSX.Element
}

function ChildComponent<T extends any>(props: ChildComponentProps<T>) {
    return (
        <div>
            {props.renderItem(props.source)}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Hope it helps!